# bigger height and width image is not occupying full space in product detail page

Tags: image, product-view

please visit this link :

you can see the base image is not occupying full space

the base image is occupying full space.

product 1's image is having bigger height and width size but why the product 1's image is

not occupying full space

please help me to find some solution....

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image uploaded includes white space around it:
http://www.kidsdial.com/media/catalog/product/1/1/1192_resized_5.jpg

Cropping out the white space should make it appear larger on the frontend after you upload the fixed image.